# Plotting a function without any coordinate system

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I want to plot two functions about each other without any coordinate system. Can you please show me how/ give me a hint, how I can achieve this.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain=0.125:1000,
    xmin=-10, xmax=1000,
    ymin=0, ymax=3,
    samples=400,
   % axis y line=center,
    %axis x line=middle,
]
    \addplot+[mark=none] {1+0.003*sin(x)+0.02*sin(x^2)+0.1*cos(5*x)+0.07236*cos(x)+0.1*sin(x*100)+0.068*cos(x*57)};
    \addplot+[mark=none] {1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: `axis lines=none`?

Comment: at which point in the code exactly? 
\begin{axis}[ 
lines=none,
...
]

 leads to an error

Comment: For example `\begin{axis}[axis lines=none, ...]`  But you have to use `axis lines` instead `lines`.

Comment: I think `hide axis` should work

Comment: @esdd Would you like to write up an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `axis lines=none` as an option of the `axis` environment. Note that this option is only an alias for `hide axis`. So you get the same result with both.

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=none,% 
  domain=0.125:1000,
  xmin=-10, xmax=1000,
  ymin=0, ymax=3,
  samples=400,
]
  \addplot+[mark=none]
    {1+0.003*sin(x)+0.02*sin(x^2)+0.1*cos(5*x)+0.07236*cos(x)+0.1*sin(x*100)+0.068*cos(x*57)};
  \addplot+[mark=none] {1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]